# RESTful API design (connection of resources)

Tags: php, api, rest, relationship

I'm designing an API for my web project (PHP) but run into trouble when modeling relationship between resources with properties. I would like to get some input on how to proceed.

Resources:

- Users.

  - Id.
  - Name.
  - Dogs (relationships).

    - Id.
    - Private (yes or no).
- Dogs.

  - Id.
  - Name.

Relationships:

- Many to many.

  - One user can have many dogs.
  - One dog can belong to many users.
- The relationship can be private or public.

How would you like to update the "private" property of the relationship?

Right now you would have to send a PUT request to .../api/users/{userId} including ALL relationships of that user including the updated property:

(Name can be NULL -> no Update)

- Dogs:

  - Dog.

    - ID : DogA.
    - Private: Yes.
  - Dog.

    - ID : DogB.
    - Private: No. (Updated)

I don't feel comfortable with this approach since I believe that only information that have been changed should be need to be sent to update. My idea right now is therefore to add support for only sending the updated relationship to .../api/users/{userId}:

- Dogs.

  - Dog.

    - ID : DogB.
    - Private: No. (Updated)

Before I get into work I would greatly appreciate some feedback. Maybe there is other better ways of handling the relationships between resources??

Answer (score 1):

Doing that would violate the principle that REST-Services are idempotent. This means you should be able to send the same operation twice without changing the resource with the second operation.

I'd treat the relation as a separate resource: 
Create/Update would be `PUT ../api/users/{userId}/dogs/{dogId}` with Private: Yes/No. Deleting a relation would be handled by `DELETE ../api/users/{userId}/dogs/{dogId}`.

Comment: OK, I've been thinking about a seperate resource as well. But how would you request all relationships for one user then?

Comment: @Mattias: `GET /api/users/{userId}/dogs/[dogId/]`? If `dogId` is not specified, you get all the relationships to `userId`.

Comment: To me "GET /api/users/{userId}/dogs" would actually give me all dog objects (not the relationships) that have a relation with {userId}. Otherwise I would have to query first for relationships and then each dog object individually (.../api/dogs/{dogId}) if I would like to see all dog objects of a user. That seems complicated to me...

Comment: @Mattias: For what you mentioned, what's wrong with `GET /api/users/{userId}/dogs/relationships/`?

Comment: Well. I have been thinking about an independent resource ("relationships") as well. But in that case i think it would be like: `GET /api/relationships, GET /api/relationships/{relationshipId}, GET /api/users/{userId}/relationships, GET /api/dogs/{dogId}/relationships`. That might actually be the most clean solution the way that I see it..